# Amazon S3 - can't upload files into the same folder using s3sync.exe

Tags: amazon-s3, upload

I'm trying to upload a file using S3sync.exe into a certain folder in my S3 bucket.
This is the command line : 
`S3Sync.exe -AWSAccessKeyId accKey -AWSSecretAccessKey secKey -RequestEndpoint s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com -BucketName "mybucket" -S3FolderKeyName "myfolder/" -SyncDirection upload -LocalFolderPath c:\myfolder`

I did not find any problems at the first upload, but a problem occured at the second upload.
Here is the log :

> Program started.   25/05/2012 12:25:20
>   Getting files on S3.
>      File added to S3 list.   KeyName=mybucket/abc.txt
>      Number of items in S3 list: 1
>   Getting local files.
>      Number of items in local list: 1
>   Deleting items on S3 (2 items):
>      Delete S3 file failed.   KeyName=mybucket/abc.txt   An error occurred.
>      Amazon Error Message: Access Denied
>      Canceling deletion of extra files on S3.
>      Number of items deleted: 0
>   Program complete.   25/05/2012 12:25:22   ExitCode=-1

Why do the S3sync.exe always try to delete the files before upload the local file?
It causes the program can't upload files into the same folder at the second upload.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you have read permissions but not write permissions - have you checked your ACL permissions for that particular file?